# Unity 3d Change Texture after Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, texture2d

I have a script attached to a Gameobject. I have also a button. When the button is pressed the file explorer opens and allow to select a custom image from PC and after importing original texture of Gameobject changes. But when I exit and run again then the custom texture replaces with original one. I want to save a custom texture instead of original texand then an option to delete the custom and go back to original tex. Please help me in this. Sorry for my bad english. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;


public class ChangeTex : MonoBehaviour 

{
    string path;
    public MeshRenderer mRenderer;

    public void OpenExplorer()
    {
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Overwrite with png", "", "png");
        GetImage();
    }

    void GetImage()
    {
        if (path != null)
        {
            UpdateImage();
        }
    }
    void UpdateImage()
    {
        byte[] imgByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (2, 2);
        texture.LoadImage(imgByte);

        mRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is store path to your image in [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). It's a Platform-independent feature that allows you to put and get some player settings in device storage. Storing it in device storage allows you get your data after re-starting application.

To save your settings to storage You have to put it and save:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString(IMAGE_PATH_KEY, path);
```

Getting settings:

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(IMAGE_PATH_KEY))
{
    path = PlayerPrefs.GetString(IMAGE_PATH_KEY);
}
```

Then instead of calling `OpenExplorer()` you can check your path in PlayerPrefs in `Start()` or `Awake()` first

Comment: No luck. Suggest me any android code like this because its not building on android platform  with save function, please.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! You don't need to call empty Save(). So all You gonna do is call `SetString(KEY, VALUE)`. I've just edited my answer